# Function from same class of dynamic list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working with a list of items and I need to set a function when a button is clicked. The list is filled dynamically from a php script, the problem is that when I click on the button, the first entry is ok, (displays correct information), but the others display the info from the first item.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <th>
    Nombre Local
  </th>
  <th>
    Direccion
  </th>
  <th>
    Hora de cierre
  </th>
  <th>
    Informacion
  </th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php foreach($list as $item){
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$item['name'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$item['addr'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$item['closing'].'</td>';
  echo '<td><button class="btn btn-data detalle" data-id="'.$item['id'].'" data-tipo="'.$item['tipo'].'" onclick="GetLocalesMain()"</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  '};?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

the JS

```
 function GetLocalesMain(){
  var informacion =  $(".detalle");
  var id = informacion.data('id');
  var tipo = informacion.data('tipo');

  console.log(id);
  console.log(tipo);
  $.ajax({
    url: '../functions/procesa.php?item=' + id + '&tipo=' + tipo,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    complete: function (xhr, textStatus){
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
     console.log('json', data);
     $(data).each(function(a){
       muestraData(this);
     });
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The information that is sent by ajax is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are getting all instances of `".detalle"` e.g. `var informacion = $(".detalle");` but you need to target the item clicked, you can do this quite simply using jquery (as you are using it anyway).

You could remove `onclick="GetLocalesMain()"` in your html and in the javascript place the contents of your `GetLocalesMain` function inside the following jquery click function:

```
$( ".detalle").click(function() {
  // function contents goes here
});
```

Then replace `var informacion = $(".detalle");` with `var informacion = $(this);`

You should now get the clicked item and subsequently the right data.